# How to monitor Ethernet packet loss real time on different connections?

Tags: ethernet, monitor, statistics, quality

For an embedded application we have a network with star topology, where we want to determine if there is packet loss for the different point-to-point (SMAC => DMAC) connections.

We consider inventing some scheme where the source (SMAC) sends a statistics packet every second to each of the know destinations (DMACs) with information about number of packets transmitted the previous second. When the destination (DMAC) then receives the statistics packet, it can then check the transmitted packet number against the number of packets actually received, whereby any packet loss is revealed.

The solution will be implemented in and FPGA, and placed close to the MAC, so the statistics packets can be removed at low level, so higher level protocols is not to consider this addition.

Is there any known scheme, e.g. an existing standard for doing monitoring like the above?

Comment: Is this raw ethernet or do you do anything like IP on top? This sounds like you want some kind of network layer, and usually you'd define that as layer 3 protocol, that's why I'm asking. If it's raw ethernet: do you have any specific packet structure in there, e.g. a small packet counter?

Comment: There can be different protocols on top, e.g. IP, UDP, ARP etc.  The intention is the measure the quality of the layer 2 connection (link), independent on higher layer protocols.

Comment: ah, sorry, now your third paragraph makes sense in my head!

Answer (score 1):

You have a small problem: Between the count that you need to put into your packet and that packet actually being sent, other (payload) packets might be sent. You need to give your status packets some kind of priority, or let them parse the queue (if any).

Architecturally: if you have TX queues, where you can insert packets at the head (or if you can afford a second queue just for these kinds of packets, which always gets emptied first):
Instead of "once every second", I'd go with "once every N packets", per DMAC. (You're increasing an entry in some table synchronously, anyway, so that's a pretty easy to check for condition. "All" you'd have to do then is insert a packet head-of-queue in the single queue case, or just anywhere in the queue with a dedicated status message queue.)

> The solution will be implemented in and FPGA, and placed close to the MAC, so the statistics packets can be removed at low level, so higher level protocols is not to consider this addition.

Why, though? This kind of thing happens at low rates, and it probably has higher-layer consequences. Sounds like something you should ideally do in software, e.g., in a small softcore or a host OS. You could make your FPGA just detect that packet, and append the actual number of received packets to it – then the software can read both the transmitted "should-be" and the received "is" value, and can report, take corrective action or reset the link, for example.

Because ethernet doesn't have sequence numbers in itself, and because a network card couldn't on its own do anything with that knowledge, I'm not aware of any low-level protocols for this kind of information exchange. Candidates include the PPP-include *Link Quality Report* (but yours doesn't sound like a use case for this), or simply one of the reserved types in ICMPv6.

For an easy implementation: use your own Ethertype field value in the Ethernet header, put in the current frame count, or even leave it out, if it's implicit by sending these packets every N frames, have your receiver handle these packets by appending the receive frame count (or just replacing the count with the difference!), and then handle said frame in software.

If you happen to have an ARP table on your sender, I'd skip all that and simply craft an UDP packet to the right IP address, and just handle that. Matching Ethertype == 0x86DD or 0x0800 (IPv6 or IPv4), IP proto number == 0x11 (UDP), Destport == 0x… … at fixed positions literally requires a 5-octet fixed-value fixed-position comparison, so it's really cheap to do in your destination FPGA.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough input and suggestions, which I will take into account.  The reason for doing it in HW (FPGA) close to the MAC, is that there are other features in HW that generates packages, e.g. [Parallel Redundancy Protocol (PRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Redundancy_Protocol), which is handled after the SW level protocol stack.  There will be an ARP like table in the statistics system, but lookup implementation can be a simple iteration, since there is at most 30 nodes and the rate is only 100 Mbps.  Good idea with the specific Ethertype, for simple filtering.